# how to get the name and other details by iterating through index values of list which stores the data read from the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
class Rec:
cust = []

def readCust(self):
    with open('customer.txt', 'r') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for line in reader:      
            self.cust.append(line)

        for i in len(self.cust):
            print(self.cust[1])

    return self.cust
```

I am trying to get the names which are stored at the index position [1] in cust list after appending, so that when I called for ciraj it will check if its available in cust list and if it is available it will return the 8.5 so that I can multiply it with quantity which I'm asking the user

```
8, ciraj, w , 8.5, 700
9, eraj, r , 12.5, 50
10, kraj, w , 10, 450
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure about what you were trying to do, but you can't iterate integers, and using lists to save data of a "name" is a bad idea, but if you really want to work with lists:

```
import csv
class Rec:
    cust = []
    def readCust(self):
        with open('test.txt', 'r') as csv_file:
            reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            for line in reader:
                self.cust.append(line)
        return self.cust

    def getNum(self, name):  
        for c in self.cust:
            if c[1].strip() == name:
                return c[3]
            else:
                pass
    def getCustomer(self, name):
        for c in self.cust:
            if c[1].strip() ==name:
                return c
            else:
                pass
 #note: I used strip() because there are blank spaces before the name   


a = Rec()
a.readCust()
print(a.getCustomer('eraj'))
print('number: ',a.getNum('eraj'))
print(a.getCustomer('ciraj'))
print('number: ',a.getNum('ciraj'))
```

output:

```
['9', ' eraj', ' r ', ' 12.5', ' 50']
number:   12.5
['8', ' ciraj', ' w ', ' 8.5', ' 700']
number:   8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to change the way you store the data in your class. For example a list of `dict`s will allow you to access your data in a more easy to read way.

```
import csv
class Rec:
    cust = []
    
    def readCust(self):
        with open(r'customer.txt', 'r') as csv_file:
            reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            for l in reader:
                cCust = { 'idx':l[0].strip(),
                         'name':l[1].strip(),
                         'var1':l[2].strip(),
                         'var2':l[3].strip(),
                         'var3':l[4].strip()}
                
                self.cust.append(cCust)
    
    def printNames(self):
            for i in self.cust:
                print(i['name'])
    
    def getCust(self, custName):
        
        for i in self.cust:
            if i['name'] == custName:
                return i
        return None
```

With this you can do things like this

```
>>> r = Rec()
>>> r.readCust()

>>> r.printNames()
ciraj
eraj
kraj

>>> cust = r.getCust('ciraj')
>>> print(cust)
{'idx': '8', 'name': 'ciraj', 'var1': 'w', 'var2': '8.5', 'var3': '700'}
```

If you want to keep you current structure, the quick fix for your verions would look like this.

```
 for i in self.cust:
    if 'ciraj' in i[1]:
        return i[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood correctly what you are trying to do, but I suggest following sourcecode:

```
import csv
class Rec:
    cust = []
    def readCust(self,name):
        with open('customer.txt', 'r') as csv_file:
            for line in csv.reader(csv_file):
                if line[1].strip()==name:
                    return line[3].strip()
```